# cgo cross compiling from amd64(linux) to arm64(linux)

Tags: linux, cross-compiling, cgo, gccgo

I am trying to build a go code for "arm64" architecture from "amd64" using a arm64 based so. I get the below mentioned error when I build the go code with the shared library. Can someone please assist me on this?

Go Version: 
go1.10.3 linux/amd64

gcc version: 
gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-21ubuntu1~16.04)

go env:

```
GOARCH="arm64"
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

Error: 
go build hello.go

```
# runtime/cgo
gcc_arm64.S: Assembler messages:
gcc_arm64.S:27: Error: no such instruction: `stp x19,x20,[sp,'
gcc_arm64.S:28: Error: no such instruction: `stp x21,x22,[sp,'
gcc_arm64.S:29: Error: no such instruction: `stp x23,x24,[sp,'
gcc_arm64.S:30: Error: no such instruction: `stp x25,x26,[sp,'
gcc_arm64.S:31: Error: no such instruction: `stp x27,x28,[sp,'
gcc_arm64.S:32: Error: no such instruction: `stp x29,x30,[sp,'
gcc_arm64.S:33: Error: too many memory references for `mov'
gcc_arm64.S:35: Error: too many memory references for `mov'
gcc_arm64.S:36: Error: too many memory references for `mov'
gcc_arm64.S:37: Error: too many memory references for `mov'
gcc_arm64.S:39: Error: no such instruction: `blr x20'
gcc_arm64.S:40: Error: no such instruction: `blr x19'
gcc_arm64.S:42: Error: no such instruction: `ldp x29,x30,[sp],'
gcc_arm64.S:43: Error: no such instruction: `ldp x27,x28,[sp],'
gcc_arm64.S:44: Error: no such instruction: `ldp x25,x26,[sp],'
gcc_arm64.S:45: Error: no such instruction: `ldp x23,x24,[sp],'
gcc_arm64.S:46: Error: no such instruction: `ldp x21,x22,[sp],'
gcc_arm64.S:47: Error: no such instruction: `ldp x19,x20,[sp],'
```

Go Code:

```
package main
/*
#cgo CFLAGS: -I./cgolang/include
#cgo LDFLAGS: -L./cgolang/lib  -laxxxxxx
#include "axxxxxx.h"
*/
import "C"
import "fmt"

func main() {
fmt.Printf("hello, world\n")
}
```

Comment: You need to show how you configured, and how the source files are being compiled.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem when I needed to build a static Go binary with cgo that would eventually run in an *alpine* container with *arm64* architecture, but had to be built in a *golang:alpine* container with *x86_64* architecture (I didn't have control over the CI/CD runner architecture).

I solved it like the answer from @jesse but wanted to include an example for completeness since I was confused about where to get the cross-compiler and which files in it to use. Here is an example of downloading/extracting the CC in the container user's home directory and using it in a go build based out of `/usr/src/example` that produces an executable named *exampleApp*.

```bash
wget -P ~ https://musl.cc/aarch64-linux-musl-cross.tgz
tar -xvf ~/aarch64-linux-musl-cross.tgz -C ~
cd /usr/src/example
GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm64 CGO_ENABLED=1 CC=~/aarch64-linux-musl-cross/bin/aarch64-linux-musl-gcc go build -o exampleApp -a -ldflags=-extldflags=-static .
```

Running `file` on the `exe` output verified it was statically linked for
aarch64. I was then able to run it in an arm64 alpine container elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I linked the math library like so #cgo LDFLAGS: -L./cgolang/lib -lpthread -lm

That worked for me.
If your shared library is provided by a third party, please ask them to help you out

Answer (score 0):

```
env CGO_ENABLED=1 GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm64 CC=/path/to/your/arm64/gcc go build hello.go
```

you could see this same issue:https://github.com/golang/go/issues/8161